# Where is the information stored in a html? (web-scraping)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

A beginner here.
I want to extract all the jobs from Barclays (https://search.jobs.barclays/search-jobs)

I got through scraping the first page but am struggling to go to the next page, as the url don't change.
I tried to scrape the url on the next page button, but that href brings me back to the homepage.

Does that mean that all the job data is actually stored within the original html?
If so, how can I extract it?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably input some data to get to the second page. Thus, you cant directly access the second one. More details are needed..

Comment: The job data is fetched by Javascript using XHR. If you open your browser's network inspector on that page you can see the requests that are executed when you switch between pages. If you want all pages, you'll have to scrape those URLs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I analyzed the website, and it communicates with the server using an API, so you can get data directly from it as a JSON file.

This is the API link in this specific case(for my computer): https://search.jobs.barclays/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=44699&CurrentPage=2&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&ShowRadius=False&IsPagination=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=0&SearchType=5&PostalCode=&fc=&fl=&fcf=&afc=&afl=&afcf=

For you the url might be different, but the concept is the same:
As you ca see, there is a 'CurrentPage=2' inside the url which you can use to get any of the pages using requests, then extract what you need from the json.